# Token range selects with secondary index filtering in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to do token range table scans in cassandra while also applying secondary index filtering?

Comment: Have you attempted anything yourself, or run into a specific error?

Comment: I'm going to use Stratio to do complex secondary index filtering on token range queries, but I read somewhere that you can only use = to filter partition keys with secondary indices, so I didn't understand how this could work.

Comment: I just confirmed this does work.  I don't know why the documentation would be so misleading.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.  I was confused because the cassandra documentation said you may only use = on the partition key when filtering with secondary indices.  Not sure why they say that.